# In Selenium, how to log in website on the popup window with python?

Tags: python, selenium

I would like to log in the website using selenium.
This site has link( **members login** ) and when I click this link, popup window appears.

The website URL is http://affiliates.888.com/

I wrote the code as follows.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

eight88 = webdriver.Chrome()
eight88.get("http://affiliates.888.com/")
assert "Earn Real Money" in eight88.title
loginForm = eight88.find_element_by_class_name("hide-under-480").click()
# so far popup appears.
eight88.switch_to_alert()
eight88.find_element_by_id("userName").send_keys("username")
eight88.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys("password")
```

When I run this script, `NoSuchElementException` occurs.

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"userName"}
  (Session info: chrome=59.0.3071.115)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477691 (6ee44a7247c639c0703f291d320bdf05c1531b57),platform=Linux 4.4.0-83-generic x86_64)
```

I don't know how to go to the popup and find element there.

How can I log in this website on popup.

Comment: You might have to wait a few tens of a second for the popup to appear and/or check that it popped up and then proceed with filling things out with your username/password.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have added code such as eight88.implicitly_wait(10) but same exception has occurred. how can I handle it?

Comment: For that you can use ExplicitWait but if the JavaScript is designed in a way that it doesn't include the new fields into the original page source, this wouldn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Authorization form is located inside an `iframe`, not alert. To be able to handle elements inside `iframe` you should switch to it first:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait

eight88 = webdriver.Chrome()
eight88.get("http://affiliates.888.com/")
assert "Earn Real Money" in eight88.title
loginForm = eight88.find_element_by_class_name("hide-under-480")
loginForm.click()

wait(eight88, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(eight.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[contains(@src, "Auth/Login")]')))

eight88.find_element_by_id("userName").send_keys("username")
eight88.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys("password")
```

Answer (score 0):

The pop up is being generated by a JavaScript. So this is a dynamic page. When you use driver.get() you're reading the first static page source that is generated and obviously the username and password fields are not included. First figure out how the JavaScript is invoking the pop up and then use selenium's exec function to execute that JavaScript and another one to authenticate over the result of the first one.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Would you explain about it in details with some snippet of code?

Comment: Unfortunately, you need to know JavaScript to reverse engineer it and so I'm afraid I might not be to help. Tag JavaScript in the question and post the js which is responsible for this pop-up and more importantly, the js which performs the authentication. If it simply returns a POST request, this is easy.